# How to handle random popup/alert/error that may appear anywhere and anytime in a windows application using WinAppDriver and Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse, winappdriver

I have a scenario where I am testing a Windows based application using WinAppDriver and Selenium TestNG framework. While testing the application, it may throw random alerts/pop-ups/error messages at any point of time.
I would like to handle that in my code and close that alert/pop-up/error message and carry on with my automation testing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This may help you: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html  and possibly unhandledpromptbehaviour.